# It should have been an infinite loop

Tags: python, loops

I wrote a code in python. While changing the code, I asked myself what should be the output.
I also answered myself it should be an infinite loop. Then I ran it. But surprisingly it wasn't an infinite loop. My question is why ?

```
i=0
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5:
        i -=1
    else:
        print(i)
    i+=1
```

Comment: Why do you think it is an infinite loop? The looping variable takes value from the `range(10)`, so it is supposed to run 10 times. You just skip printing 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very basic in python. For your information, the `range()` function generates a list. Here `range(5)` means `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

So `i` iterates through the list `[0,1,2,3,4]` one by one. `i` doesn't hold the same value initialized from the beginning like a `while` loop condition.

```
for i in [0,1,2,3,4]:
  if i==5:
    i-=1
  else:
    print(i)
  i+=1
```

Your code and this code perform similarly. The next value of `i` doesn't depend on the previous value of `i` but on the objects of the list.
Further study might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

`range(10)` produces the sequence `0,1,...,9` from which your `i` variable takes its values in the loop. The fact that you do `i -= 1` when `i == 5` won't make `i` to switch back and forth from `5` to `4` on and on because `i` is taking its values from `range(10)`. What happens when `i == 5` is that it becomes `i == 4` when you do `i -= 1` but at the next iteration `i` will take the next value from the `range` which would be `6`, and so on until the loop ends.

Here's an infinite loop:

```
i=0
while i < 10:
    if i == 5:
        i -=1
    else:
        print(i)
    i+=1
```